# Exception "Specified method is not supported." being thrown from NHibernate IQueryable expression when using .Any extension

Tags: c#, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, notsupportedexception

Utilizing NHibernate I am attempting to use a lambda expression to retrieve objects based on the status and values between a parent child relationship. `AbstractWorkflowRequestInformation` has a collection of `WorkflowRequestInformationAction`. Each of the two classes have their own Status properties. To illustrate here are the abbreviated classes as they relate to this query:

```
public class AbstractWorkflowRequestInformation
{
    public virtual RequestStatus RequestStatus { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<WorkflowRequestInformationAction>
        WorkflowRequestInformationActionList { get; set; }
}

public class WorkflowRequestInformationAction
{
    public virtual ActionStatus Status { get; set; }

    public virtual string RoleIdentifier { get; set; }

    public virtual string RoleName { get; set; }
}
```

Given this relationship I want to retrieve AbstractWorkflowRequestInformation objects based on a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` called roles. I realize that the exception is being caused by a lack of parsing of the `Any(...)` extension method, but I am unsure of alternative queries. Thus far all permutations on the below query have caused the same or similar exceptions:

```
public IEnumerable<IRequestInformation> GetRequestsPendingActionBy(
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> roles)
{
    var results = GetSession().Query<AbstractWorkflowRequestInformation>()
        .Where(r => r.RequestStatus == RequestStatus.Pending
                    && r.WorkflowRequestInformationActionList
                        .Any(a => ActionStatus.Pending == a.Status
                                  && roles.Any(kp => kp.Key == a.RoleName
                                               && kp.Value == a.RoleIdentifier)))
    .ToList();

    return results;
}
```

The ultimate goal is to retrieve only those `AbstractWorkflowRequestInformation` objects which are pending and have a pending WorkflowRequestInformationAction matching a KeyValuePair in the roles enumerable.

I am not wedded to using a lambda expression as this expression has already grown unwieldy, if there's a more elegant ICriteria expression I am all ears. What are my options to restrict my results based upon the values in my `roles List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` but prevent the "Specified method is not supported" exception?

Comment: short answer...don't use NH Linq

Comment: @dotjoe I'm amenable to that answer, but do you have an alternative using HQL, ICriteria etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would get same results...

```
WorkflowRequestInformationAction actionAlias = null;

var q = GetSession().QueryOver<AbstractWorkflowRequestInformation>()
    .Inner.JoinAlias(x => x.WorkflowRequestInformationActionList,
                          () => actionAlias)
    .Where(x => x.RequestStatus == RequestStatus.Pending)
    .And(() => actionAlias.Status == ActionStatus.Pending);

var d = Restrictions.Disjunction();

foreach(var kvp in roles) 
{
    d.Add(Restrictions.Where(() => actionAlias.RoleName == kvp.Key
                                  && actionAlias.RoleIdentitifier == kvp.Value));
}

q.And(d).TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity);

var results = q.List();
```

You could probably take a similar approach with NH Linq. I'm more comfortable with QueryOver/Criteria though.

Comment: This did the trick. Upon additional reading I am definitely coming to the conclusion that NHibernate's Linq implementation is not yet ready for prime-time. As someone said somewhere it should have come with a giant beta disclaimer. Thanks for the elegant solution utilizing QuveryOver/Criteria!

Comment: good to hear. I think the NH devs quit on the Linq provider. They can provide a lot sweeter features with QueryOver.

Comment: it certainly seems that way. An unfortunate state of affairs because Linq feels more "natural." That said I prefer using things that work vs. what feels natural. ;)

Comment: Be aware that there have been significant improvements to LINQ in NH 3.3.

Answer (score 1):

The LINQ provider in NHibernate is not fully supported, you are trying to execute an extension method on a part of the expression tree that is not parsed from the provider.

This [post](http://www.primordialcode.com/blog/post/nhibernate-3-extending-linq-provider-fix-notsupportedexception) might help you solve the problem. Be sure to checkout the related posts.

Also see the post from Fabio Maulo on [NHibernate LINQ provider extension](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.it/2010/07/nhibernate-linq-provider-extension.html).